# Confused about Ruby on Rails REST Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am really confused about Ruby on Rails REST routing. Even though I have specified that after the success it should go to the confirm action it goes to the show action and pass the ID=confirm.

```
 def create

    @article = Article.new(params[:article])

    respond_to do |format|
    if @article.save 
      format.html { redirect_to :action => "confirm" }
    else 
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
    end 

    end

  end
```

The error I get is the following:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ArticlesController#show

Couldn't find Article with ID=confirm
Rails.root: /Projects/highoncoding

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:31:in `show'

UPDATE 1:

Here is my Route.rb file:

```
 resources :articles

  get "articles/confirm"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need to add the route so it looks like

```
match 'articles/confirm/', :controller => 'article', :action => 'confirm'
resources :articles
```

you need to have the :id in there or it will think that confirm is an id which is why you are seeing the error ID=confirm. make sure also that this is the first route. (at least before the resources for the articles controller.

Comment: Even after defining the route as u mentioned I get the following Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"confirm", :controller=>"articles"}

Comment: Check to make sure you have 'articles' and not article, as @Jeremy has above.

Comment: controller needs to be article, singular, not plural. Also, make sure you have the :id segment, and then you should probably pass the :id in your redirect_to

Comment: My controller is called "articles_controller" not "article".

Comment: I see you don't want the id of the current one at all, you can leave that out then obviously.

Comment: That looks like Rails 2 routing with a touch of Rails 3 sprinkled on top.

Comment: @azamsharp, yes, but remember the ruby convention, it will pick up the rest of the controller name for you. Go with the singular 'article' and you'll be fine

Comment: Thanks! the reason it was not working was I had the :id and it was expecting the id to be passed. I do not want to pass anything so I removed the :id part and now it works fine! Thanks!

Comment: @Jeremy B. But in the Rails documentation they say to use plural names for controllers specially when using RESTful urls.

Comment: Removing the :id to remove confusion.

Answer (score 2):

```
# config/routes.rb
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :articles do
    member do
      get 'confirm'
    end
  end

end

# app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @article = Article.new(params[:article])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        # use a named route here
        format.html { redirect_to confirm_article_url(@article) }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
      end 
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: I prefer this one using the confirm `member` .

Answer (score 1):

You should probably add the confirm route directly in your routes file.

```
match 'articles/confirm' => 'articles#confirm'
```

`resources` only work for create/update/destroy/etc.

Comment: I have the following:   resources :articles

  get "articles/confirm"

Comment: That only works for the RESTful actions. You're adding new functionality (confirm), and have to explicitly define it.